# Logging Spring Integration exceptions using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have experienced some exceptions ( mainly Channel without consumer ) in our Spring Integration pipeline. But those exceptions are lost and we dont see them unless we run the app and look at the console.

Is there any way to log those exceptions to a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot uses logback by default. Add a suitably configured logback.xml to the class path.